# Spring controller, custom response via HttpServletResponse

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write a custom response using `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` and `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int)`.

But anything that is an status different from 200 doesn't consideres the response body that I wrote.

I have 2 web applications running on different ports, the application "A" must request data from application "B". For this I created a controller to tunnel all requests on application "A" to application "B".

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/tunnel/**")
public void exchange(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
   // my service tunnel the request to another server
   // and the response of the server must be replied

   ResponseDescriptor tunnelResponse = tunnelService.request(request);

   response.setStatus(tunnelResponse.getStatus()); 
   // if the status was different them 200, the next line will not work 
   response.getOutputStream().write(tunnelResponse.getResponseBodyAsByteArray());
}
```

Note, I need to response from application A the exact response that come from application B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I created a `@ExceptionHandler` and a custom exception `TunnelException extends RuntimeException`.

So, on my `exchange(...)` method, I catch `RestClientResponseException` and throw my own exception encapsulating (in the exception) the `Headers`, `HttpStatus` and the `ResponseBody byte array`.

This is the exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(TunnelException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleTunnelException(TunnelException ex) throws IOException {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(ex.getStatus())
            .contentType(ex.getHeaders().getContentType())
            .body(ex.getBody());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch HttpStatusCodeException to get responses other than 200.

```
try {
    ResponseDescriptor tunnelResponse = tunnelService.request(request);
    response.setStatus(tunnelResponse.getStatus());
    response.getOutputStream().write(tunnelResponse.getResponseBodyAsByteArray());
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    response.setStatus(e.getStatusCode().value());
    response.getOutputStream().write(e.getResponseBodyAsByteArray());
}
```

Comment: I already doing this. I catch this exception and return the response exception info in the ResponseDescriptor too.

Comment: Are you using spring restTemplate to call this? Can you share that piece of code?

Comment: This solution does not worked. The status code returns, but the body is always empty.